# Using multiple accounts to get around Stack Exchange Questions limit

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, user-accounts

Is it allowed to use multiple accounts to ask questions on the same topics, in this forum to get around the limit of 6 questions per day?

I really [like an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127567/why-are-we-limited-to-six-questions-per-day?newreg=409f4275af2442a58d209265d7eea122) as to why we are not allowed to ask more than 6 questions per day. But is there actually a rule against it?

> Because if you've asked 6 questions in a 24 hour period, that's a sign
> it's time to do some research on your own, or actually get some work
> done.
>
> Seriously, that's a lot. It has nothing to do with the possible
> reputation gain and everything to do with the fact that this is a site
> staffed entirely by volunteers, who give freely of their own time and
> expertise to answer your questions. You're just taking advantage of
> that unjustifiably if you don't expend any effort to find answers to
> your questions on your own.
>
> Asking this many questions is almost always a good sign that you're
> not putting enough effort into each question. There's no way you can
> research and write more than 6 quality questions in a 24 hour period.
> At least not if you sleep and eat and all those other things. And if
> you're not doing those things, then consider this question limit a
> public service for your health.
>
> Moreover, keep in mind that there are other users who wish to use and
> benefit from the site as well. All of the questions you ask
> necessarily draw time and attention away from the questions posted by
> other users. Spreading questions out over a longer period of time
> gives everyone a more reasonable chance for their questions to "shine"
> (i.e., appear on the home page).

For example, I think, these accounts are owned by the same person:

- [John Gu](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15355/john-gu)
- [John John](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/84413/john-john)
- [NETCoreSharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/107008/netcoresharepoint) (Credits to [Derek Gusoff](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8056/derek-gusoff)) Update

**Evidence that these accounts belong to the same person**

- **John Gu** and **John John** are very similar account names
- Both accounts only ask questions and never answer them: John John asked **438** questions / gave **1** answer. John Gu asked **1112** questions / gave **22** answers.
- Both accounts often prefer not to capitalize "I" when they refer to themselves.
  [image]
- Both accounts use MS paint for highlighting screenshots with a rectangle that is **exactly 5 pixels** in width:
  [image]
- both accounts are interested in exactly the same task at the same time:

**Example. John Gu exceeded 6 questions per day limit and had to use John John to ask the same question again**
[image]

**Another example. Same question about lookups and 1+ million items support**
[image]

John also cross-posts the same questions to at least **4 sites at the same time**. Stack Exchange, [techcommunity.microsoft.com](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/) and to [Microsoft's forum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-sharepoint-online.html).

**Example of Cross-site posting with nearly identical question**

- [What are the risks of deploying the react-script-editor web part inside our SharePoint online tenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/624374/what-are-the-risks-of-deploying-the-react-script-e.html)
- [What are the risks (if any) if we install the react-script-editor web part inside our SharePoint online tenant](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298820/what-are-the-risks-if-any-if-we-install-the-react-script-editor-web-part-insid)
- [Any security issue in using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render HTMLCode inside react.js sharepoint webpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897822/any-security-issue-in-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-to-render-htmlcode-inside-re)
- [Secure way to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML inside my react SharePoint Modern web part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901000/secure-way-to-use-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-inside-my-react-sharepoint-modern-web)
- [Is there any security issue in using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render HTML Code inside our React.js sharepoint modern web-part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298751/is-there-any-security-issue-in-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-to-render-html-code)
- [Available SPFx webpart which can allow us to inject custom css files per modern pages, without the ability to inject custom JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/624663/available-spfx-webpart-which-can-allow-us-to-injec.html)
- [3rd party SPFx which i can use to inject custom css files inside different modern pages by specifying the cusotm css url](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/624322/3rd-party-spfx-which-i-can-use-to-inject-custom-cs.html)

**Another Example of Cross-site posting with nearly identical question**

- [Build an SPFX web part which render an HTML BOX which have a configurable Title, Description and Clickable Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687376/build-an-spfx-web-part-which-render-an-html-box-which-have-a-configurable-title)
- [SPFX web part to add Text and show it inside a Popup when clicking on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860702/spfx-web-part-to-add-text-and-show-it-inside-a-popup-when-clicking-on-a-button)
- [Can I show Rich-Text inside Popups which rendered when clicking on 2 buttons inside SharePoint SPFX web part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888474/can-i-show-rich-text-inside-popups-which-rendered-when-clicking-on-2-buttons-ins)
- [SPFx web part to add Text and show it inside a Popup when clicking on a button](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298697/spfx-web-part-to-add-text-and-show-it-inside-a-popup-when-clicking-on-a-button)
- [Can I show a Rich Text inside Popup for our SPFX web part instead of Plain-Text](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298735/can-i-show-a-rich-text-inside-popup-for-our-spfx-web-part-instead-of-plain-text)
- [Can I show a Rich Text inside Popup for our SPFX web part instead of Plain-Text](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/can-i-show-a-rich-text-inside-popup-for-our-spfx-web-part/m-p/2940501)
- [SPFX web part to add Text and show it inside a Popup when clicking on a button](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/spfx-web-part-to-add-text-and-show-it-inside-a-popup-when/m-p/2933524)

There are multiple other examples.

So what do you recommend? Everything is fine? Or something isn't right here?

Comment: Thank you @denis for your great effort to raise such cases in our community! actually, I don't have a clear answer right now. however, let me share your question with our Community manager and other moderators, and will feedback to you soon!

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP Is the limit 6 questions per day (and 50 questions per month) actually enabled on [sharepoint.se]? The FAQ post on [meta.se] says that only four sites in the network have such limit, see: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899#164900) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/164900/136)).

Comment: Well, I once faced this limit myself on this forum when I tried asking 7 questions on a same day. One separate question about each undocumented SharePoint Online site collection feature.

Comment: In my view, creating two accounts to get around the restrictions of the site is bad behaviour and should be dealt with by moderators.

If you are able to create multiple accounts to ask more questions, what is stopping you upvoting your own questions with a second account to ensure your question gets the most visibility.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use multiple accounts to do anything that you wouldn't be able to do with just account (including circumventing system restrictions).

Comment: same person: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/107008/netcoresharepoint

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - It's not allowed, and you should raise a moderator flag for moderators to investigate and handle as appropriate.

---

The general rule for multiple accounts is "don't do anything you can't do with only one account". Normally, that applies to things like voting, accepting, reviewing, etc. However, it also applies to "hitting the system-imposed ceiling on number of questions asked per day".

If you are not yet convinced, let's apply the same argument but just lower the numbers to someone who has a "full" question ban, imposed by the system automatically. In a full suspension of asking privileges, a user is only allowed to post one question every 6 months.

If this user creates another account to ask more questions, that's considered an attempt to circumvent a ban, and is not allowed. It is, essentially, creating a new account to get around a system-imposed limit, which is exactly what this user is doing. Do your civic duty (not to be confused with the Civic Duty badge...) and raise a custom moderator flag if you see this.